# How to Cancel Retrofit request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I scroll through the official [documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests) of Retrofit and decided to implement something like this in my project, so that the user always has the option to cancel the download file and everything would work correctly. Implement appropriate methods, where the failure to prescribe the following:

```
service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final ImageUpload imageUpload, Response response) {
                mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                if (error.isCanceled()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "request is cancelled");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
                }
            }
```

But underlines in red **isCanceled** in failure method. I do not understand what's the problem, because this method we initially proposed class *Call*(perhaps because swears at me instead of class Call is RetrofitError?) Please tell me how to fix.
I use retrofit 1.9, and i don't need go on retrofit 2.

Comment: is isCanceled() an existing method for that type, and is it correctly spelled?

Comment: are you using retrofit 1 or retrofit 2?. I think isCanceled is introduced in Retrofit2

Comment: read document carefully.........isCancelled() method is of **retrofit2.Call** class not **RetorfitError** class

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`error.isCanceled()` does not seem to be there in Retrofit as far as I remember. If you want to be able to cancel a request, you can either switch to Retrofit 2 where they have a `call.cancel()` method or in the current version of Retrofit, you could extent the `Callback` class to create your own class `CancellableCallback` like this:

```
public class CancellableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private Callback<T> callback;

    private boolean canceled;

    private CancellableCallback() {}

    public CancellableCallback(Callback<T> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        canceled = false;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        canceled = true;
        callback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T o, Response response) {
        if (!canceled) {
            callback.success(o, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (!canceled) {
            callback.failure(error);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can then use it like this:

```
CancellableCallback callback = new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final ImageUpload imageUpload, Response response) {
                mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
    };

service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, callback);
```

And then cancel it like this:

```
if (some condition && callback != null) {
    callback.cancel();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying, I will add more explanation to my answer.

Comment: what happened if the request uploading a big size file ? :/ should the file continue uploading without user knowing ?

Answer (score 14):

You can Cancel Request like:

```
// something happened, for example: user clicked cancel button
service.cancel();
```

and get callback of Cancel like:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
       if (call.isCanceled()) {
           Log.e(TAG, "request was cancelled");
       }
       else {
           Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
       }
}
```

You can check [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests) for more.

Comment: thank you, but this example suitable for retrofit 2. In my app i used 1.9.

Comment: what is service ? what class type is that ?

Comment: @AmirZiarati `service` is a retrofit2 `Call`, we usually use it like `service.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You should use Retrofit 2 for that and change interface method signature to return a `Call` object. To do a request, you call `enqueue` method. After that, you can call `cancel` method to cancel the request.

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to retrofit2 , and then write something like this -

```
service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, new Callback<ImageUpload>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImageUpload> call, Response<Topics> response) {

            //retrieve your resbonse body here like this -
            //   ImageUpload imageUpload = response.body();
            mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ...
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImageUpload> call, Throwable t) {
            if (call.isCanceled()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "request is cancelled");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
            }
        }
```