# How to cancel retrofit Response<T> type api calls?

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, rest-client

How to cancel retrofit `Response<T>` api calls.
Like we have a function for Call class. Link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--

But there is no such thing for Response type.
Link: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't cancel after receive `Response<T>`

It's result after run `execute()`, `enqueue()`

You must use `enqueue()` and use `Call<T>.cancel()`

You want cancel Callback, here:
[How to Cancel Retrofit request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592084/how-to-cancel-retrofit-request)